# implementing openlayers-google map into ionic app

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, openlayers

I am trying to implement openlayers-google-map into my ionic3 appliation refrred from https://github.com/mapgears/ol3-google-maps . I tried to copy the example code provided in the link but not success. my html view:

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as ol from 'openlayers';
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import GoogleLayer from 'olgm/layer/Google.js';
import {defaults} from 'olgm/interaction.js';
import OLGoogleMaps from 'olgm/OLGoogleMaps.js';

constructor(public googleLayer: GoogleLayer){ };
ngOnInit(){
   var map = new ol.Map({
            interactions: olgm.interaction.defaults(),
            controls: ol.control.defaults(),
            layers: [googleLayer],
            target: 'map',
            view: new ol.View({
              center: [0, 0],
              zoom: 2
            });

             var olGM = new olgm.OLGoogleMaps({
                map: map
              }); // map is the ol.Map instance
              olGM.activate();

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.20.1/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script  type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=<my_Key>">
</script>
<script  type="text/javascript"
  src="http://dev5.mapgears.com/ol3-google-maps/dist/ol3gm.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev5.mapgears.com/ol3-google-maps/css/ol3gm.css" type="text/css" />
<ion-content>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

can anybody help to implement ol3-google map into ionic3 apps ?

Comment: any idea so far..??